# Hadoop WordCount Example

Tags: windows, eclipse, hadoop, cygwin, mapreduce

After successfully created hadoop environment, when I am going to run this wordcount example in hadoop with version 0.19.1, It gives me error like, how can I solve this

```
11/12/30 06:46:13 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1

11/12/30 06:46:14 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201112300255_0019

11/12/30 06:46:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%

11/12/30 06:46:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201112300255_0019_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED

java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:425)

11/12/30 06:46:24 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201112300255_0019_m_000003_1, Status : FAILED

java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:425)

11/12/30 06:46:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201112300255_0019_m_000003_2, Status : FAILED

java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:425)

11/12/30 06:46:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201112300255_0019_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED

java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:425)

11/12/30 06:46:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201112300255_0019_m_000002_1, Status : FAILED

java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:425)

11/12/30 06:46:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201112300255_0019_m_000002_2, Status : FAILED

java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:425)

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1232)
    at word.count.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:53)

Please help me out to resolve this error.
```

Comment: With just the errorcode (1) and no stack trace, it's difficult to identify the problem, check the log files for any errors/warnings. Also, is there any reason to use 0.19.1, it was released more than 2 years back?

Answer (score 2):

The hadoop version you use has a job tracker that manages the entire job. And for each sub part of that job (called a task) a task tracker that actually does the work.
The output you provided is the job tracker output that essentially says: a task failed.
To figure out what really went wrong inside that task you must have a look at the logfiles that belong to the failed task.

You can reach those logs via the mapreduce web interface of your cluster.